# Jenkins plugin git-parameter fetch working only once

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using **Git-parameter plugin** into **Jenkins** to build specific tag/branches. It was correctly working but now (not sure it's following and update or something) it's failing in a strange way:

- If I create a new job (or duplicate a failing one) add the git parameter to retrieve tag (or branch) and my build steps I can build right away. It shows me the full tag list and can build the one I select.
- On the second run, when I click "build with parameter" again then no list provided for the tag and with the branch I have this error :

  ```
  Command "git ls-remote -h ssh://jenkins@192.168.1.200/repo/git/xxx.git" 
  returned status code 128:
  stdout: 
  stderr: /tmp/ssh3146539705442744984.sh: line 6: ssh: command not found
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
  Please look at the Log
  ```

So it looks like access issue to the git repo but it's working on first run and I still can build same project (so doing a git checkout too) without this git parameter so I assume my git configuration / credentials are ok.

If you have any idea where to look ?

ps: Jenkins is running on the same machine as the repository (a linux)

Jenkins 2.73.2
Git plugin 3.6.2
Git Parameter Plug-In 0.8.1
Thanks,
Nicolas.

Comment: The error says it can't find ssh. Did you make sure ssh is in the path. It seems unlikely that is truly the cause, but try running a simple ssh command in a shell and just make sure that ssh is found. I'd eliminate that possibility first. (Still doesn't explain why it works the first time).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? There is an open issue for this and Windows slaves: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45480